# XSLT3 to transform JSON data to JSON in Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, saxon, xslt-3.0

My input is as follows.

```
{
    "customerDetail": {
        "productId": 3455533,
        "customerName": "TEST REDFOL",
        "vendorCustId": "66209776",
        "accountId": "6609776",
        "myCustomerId": "7777376790",
        "customerStatus": "SCHEDULED TO REMOVE",
        "ctryCode": "CA",
        "parentService": 4,
        "remId": 140
        "displayProduct": "ADT"
        "carrierNameLabel": "Carrier Name"
    }
      
}
```

I need the output as follows, where I can put custom labels

```
{
    "Name": "TEST REDFOL", "Customer Account No": "7777376790"
}
```

I need help with the XSL, need help with traversing through the JSON data.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:sequence  select="map{?*?customerName  }"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems rather straight-forward:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="." name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:sequence
      select="map { 
               'Name' : ?customerDetail?customerName, 
                'Customer Account No' : ?customerDetail?myCustomerId
              }"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online sample is here](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22json%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22.%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20select%3D%22map%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27Name%27%20%3A%20%3FcustomerDetail%3FcustomerName%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27Customer%20Account%20No%27%20%3A%20%3FcustomerDetail%3FmyCustomerId%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22customerDetail%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22productId%22%3A%203455533%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22customerName%22%3A%20%22TEST%20REDFOL%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22vendorCustId%22%3A%20%2266209776%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22accountId%22%3A%20%226609776%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22myCustomerId%22%3A%20%227777376790%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22customerStatus%22%3A%20%22SCHEDULED%20TO%20REMOVE%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ctryCode%22%3A%20%22CA%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22parentService%22%3A%204%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22remId%22%3A%20140%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22displayProduct%22%3A%20%22ADT%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22carrierNameLabel%22%3A%20%22Carrier%20Name%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D&input-type=JSON).

XDM maps are unordered so you can't prescribe the order of names.